# undefined variable isValid in C:\xampp\htdocs\nsoromma\admin\index.php on line 0

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I've been trying to get the welcome page to work in the admin section. I was getting the WSOD and added line1 only to get the following > Notice Undefined variable isValid in **C:\xampp\htdocs\nsoromma\admin\index.php** on line 0. I don't know where is the mistake and what to do. I'm stuck. Can anyone help? Thanks in anticipation.

Here is the code

```
<?php ob_start();
session_start(); ?>
<?php virtual('/nsoromma%20web/Connections/nsorommastoreconn.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) {
// For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized.
    $isValid = False;
}

{

// When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username.
// Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank.
    if (!empty($UserName)) {
// Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login.
// Parse the strings into arrays.
        $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers);
        $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups);
        if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) {
            $isValid = true;
        }
// Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username.
        if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) {
            $isValid = true;
        }
        if (($strUsers == "") && true) {
            $isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return $isValid;
}
$MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("", $MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {
    $MM_qsChar = "?";
    $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
    if (isset($QUERY_STRING) && strlen($QUERY_STRING) > 0)
        $MM_referrer .= "?" . $QUERY_STRING;
    $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo . $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
    header("Location: " . $MM_restrictGoTo);
    exit;
}
?>
<?php
$colname_rsAdmin = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
    $colname_rsAdmin = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_SESSION['MM_Username'] : addslashes($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
}
mysql_select_db($database_nsorommastoreconn, $nsorommastoreconn);
$query_rsAdmin = sprintf("SELECT * FROM admin_tbl WHERE email = '%s'", $colname_rsAdmin);
$rsAdmin = mysql_query($query_rsAdmin, $nsorommastoreconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsAdmin = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAdmin);
$totalRows_rsAdmin = mysql_num_rows($rsAdmin);
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>iamankh.com | admin section</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    Welcome <?php echo $row_rsAdmin['first']; ?>, to the admin section
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rsAdmin);
?>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like you are ending your `isAuthorized` method too soon:

```
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) {
// For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized.
    $isValid = False;
} // <-- Remove this

{ // <-- And this
....
```

Comment: Maybe the IDE 'helpfully' closed the method automatically for you.

Comment: @immulatin Thank you. I've remove them but it cause the WSOD

Comment: @jbblackman I also think you want to not the isAuthorized check: `&& !(isAuthorized("", $MM_authorizedUsers,...`. I assume that since isAuthorized is actually returning true for a valid user, then it will try to redirect them to login.php...

Comment: @immulatin I've tried echo 'this works' after line 2 and it worked but when I put it after line 3, I get WSOD

Comment: What is line 2 and 3? I have no idea what you mean by that